# 9 patch not respecting fill area

Tags: android

I have the following 9 patch (put on a grey background with an outline around to more clearly demo):

[image]

It stretches fine, but the fill area is not respected. The contents of my layout overflow the white rectangle portion. See below, the ImageView (red rectangle) in my layout is the left-most widget):

[image]

The file is saved as "bg.9.png". I'm using it as the background of these listview items like:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:background="@drawable/bg">
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting padding for the LinearLayout anywhere in your code? If so, that will override the content area of the nine-patch.

Comment: No the padding is not set anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

you must use an xml resource for that and place your src into the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg" >

</nine-patch>
```

and your bg should be like bg.9.png